# How Can I fetch the data of next 12days in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

Let's say today is 26 , Aug...
next 12 days <the rows whose launch_date belongs to the 12th day after today.>
I would like to get　in 12days data(include 0:00-23:59)   the 2020-09-07 data . -> C ,D only

Could you someone please tell me SQL..

SELECT *,(difference) from SAMPLES where launch_date > (SELECY SYSDATE from dual)???

Thank you GMB...
May I ask one more question?

- in this case, difference should be 12.
  the result should be..

```
C , 2020-09-07 05:23:33 , 12
D , 2020-09-07 11:14:33 , 12
```

I tried to use DATEDIFF. but ORA−00904 happened..

```
Samples(table name)
name,launch_date

A,2020-09-05 11:33:33
B 2020-09-06 02:34:33
C 2020-09-07 05:23:33
D 2020-09-07 11:14:33
E 2020-09-08 08:13:33
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want the rows whose `launch_date` belongs to the 12th day after today.

If so, consider:

```
select * 
from samples 
where 
    launch_date >= trunc(sysdate) + interval '12' day
    and launch_date < trunc(sysdate) + interval '13' day
```

The `where` clause can be simplified as follows:

```
where 
    launch_date >= trunc(sysdate) + 12
    and launch_date < trunc(sysdate) + 13
```

Comment: I tried to use DATEDIFF. but ORA−00904 happened.. Is it possible to show the difference on selected columns list... ?
like   name, launch_date , left
      C , 020-09-07 05:23:33 , 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use below simple query,

```
SELECT * from SAMPLES where trunc(launch_date) between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate)+12;
```